# Scraping from a Javascript Array?

Tags: php, javascript, json, file-get-contents

Here's an example page of what I'm trying to scrape...

```
[
[4056, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 171],
[4057, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 94],
[4058, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 175],
[4059, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 29],
[4051, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 13],
[4053, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '15:00', 170],
[4055, 1, 'Saturday, Aug 18 2012', '17:30', 23],
[4060, 1, 'Sunday, Aug 19 2012', '13:30', 194],
[4054, 1, 'Sunday, Aug 19 2012', '16:00', 16],
[4052, 1, 'Monday, Aug 20 2012', '20:00', 31],
[4123, 1, 'Wednesday, Aug 22 2012', '19:45', 15]
]
```

Here's the code I'd normally use for something similar...

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.thewebsite.com/info/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

$id = $jsonarray['id'];
```

But as you can see... that this isn't the same. Also, I don't even know if that first page is in JSON (it's a JS Array right?).

How would I scrape the individual items from this for putting into variables/array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data isn't valid JSON because it uses single quotes instead of double quotes to wrap strings.

If you know that the content will not contain other single quotes, other than the string wrappers then you could simply replace single with double quotes to correct the JSON format.

```
$fixedJSON = str_replace("'", '"', $str);
$data = json_decode($fixedJSON);

foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo $row[2]; // Saturday, Aug 18 2012
}
```

If the content could contain single quotes other than the string wrappers then it it will be harder to correct the JSON because you will need to only replace the wrapping quotes and handle quotes within the data which may or may not be escaped. For example double quotes will need escaping and single quotes will need the escaping removed.

Comment: Yes.. It'll be like this every time and your solution works. Thanks for keeping it simple <3

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, an ugly solution :\ you can use `str_replace` also

```
<?php
  $str  = preg_replace( "/'(.+?)'/", '"$1"', $str );
  var_dump( json_decode( $str ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.thewebsite.com/info/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

$id = $jsonarray[0][0]; // 4056
$id1 = $jsonarray[1][0]; // 4057
// etc
```

Comment: @Matyunin I tried this, but it doesn't work.. Doesn't pick up anything.

Comment: Yes, data in question is not a valid JSON, we need to use `$fixedJSON = str_replace("'", '"', $str);` like in first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the array in a variable.....

```
  var jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

  var len = jsonarray.length
  for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
       var s = myStringArray[i];
  }
```